# How to re-calculate a style on sibling elements?

Tags: css, loops, for-loop, css-selectors, less

Not sure if i'm even asking this correctly. So allow me to explain further.

HTML

```html
<div class='col'>
  <div id='q1' class='qBlock'
</div>
<div class='col'>
  <div id='q2' class='qBlock'
</div>
<div class='col'>
  <div id='q3' class='qBlock'
</div>
```

LESS

```
@qBlockBG: #ccc;
.qBlock { color: white; }
#q1: { background-color: @qBlockBG; }
#q{n}: { background-color: darken(#q{n-1}, 10%); }    <--- doesn't work, but that's the idea
```

What I want to do is have the base style for `#q1` be re-calculated for each sibling such that the color is darker for each additional sibling.  So `#q2` is 10% darker than `#q1` and `#q3` is 10% darker than `#q2`, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mock loops in LESS using a recursive mixin with a guard expression. Here's an example applied to your case:

```css
#q1 {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* recursive mixin with guard expression - condition */
.darker-qs(@color, @index) when (@index < 10) { 

  @darker-color: darken(@color, 10%);

  /* the statement */
  #q@{index} {
    background-color: @darker-color;
  }
  /* end of the statement */

  /* the next iteration's call - final expression */
  .darker-qs(@darker-color, @index + 1); 
}

/* the primary call - initialization */
.darker-qs(#ccc, 2);
```

Comment: brilliant!  thank you.  concise and clear... and applicable!  10/10 bud.

Comment: this also helped me understand the loops a lot better too.  2 for 1!  thanks again.